# Implementing a small updater for own android application?

Tags: android, apk, auto-update

A company asked me if I am able to program an Android-App for their internal process but with small mobile-device-management capabilites. I'm aware of the "enable manual apk-installation"-checkbox inside of the Android-Settings-Menu. I think it opens additional security holes if it is permanently checked.

So easiset way is to send a SMS with an URL to this APK, enable checkbox, install the update and disable checkbox manually. A lot to do, to update a program.

Coming from Windows Mobile and Symbian I was able to program a Facade.exe which starts a download and replaces some signed parts. The Application signing of Windows Mobile and Symbian allows this.

Is this possible with Android(not rooted)? I read some articles that it is possible to implement own Markets(like Amazon is doing it). Is it possible to use some of those APIs for the purpose of doing an auto-update. Where are thoes APIs, I am not able to find them.

Is this a solution:
Programming a torch-app(there are thousands around), publishing it to the android market. But with a small button to activate the whole application with a secret password. Updates can be rolled out via android market functionality.

A complete MDM (mobile device management) is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible with Android(not rooted)?

Not readily. You can use the techniques used by the Sideload Wonder Machine, extracting the requisite bits out of the SDK to do sideloads via USB. However:

1. Your `Facade.exe` implies the user runs Windows.
2. This implies that the user has the `adb` drivers for their device for Windows.

Neither of those are guaranteed.

> I read some articles that it is possible to implement own Markets(like Amazon is doing it). Is it possible to use some of those APIs for the purpose of doing an auto-update.

You can download whatever you want, such as an APK. You can tell Android to `VIEW` whatever you want, such as your APK. If you `VIEW` an APK (and have the right MIME type in your `Intent`), that will trigger an install or update. The user will be prompted about the install or update -- on an install, for example, it will give them the screen listing all the requested permissions.

Comment: Yes and no. With Facade.exe I meant a process on the smartphone. Did you see the Qt for Android demo? You can find it in Android Market it is called Animatedtiles by Bogdan Vatra. There is a package called Ministro which is able to download particular parts which are not installed yet. I don't know how the developer realized this.

Comment: @simplyTom: Qt for Android has little to do with APKs. Ministro in particular has nothing much to do with APKs. Ministro downloads ARM ports of Qt C/C++ libraries, AFAICT.

Comment: I have a rooted device now and the "root explorer" installed on it. So I can look into the hidden folder. Ministro is an APK and Animatedtiles is an APK, but Ministro is downloading additional files into /data/data/eu.necessitas.ministro/file/qt/lib  
there are libQtCore.so and libQtGui.so and other files around. So necessitas.animatedtiles can access necessitas.ministro-datafolder and dynamically link those files to the app. Okay, this a completely different approach, it is not possible to change/update parts of an APK.

Comment: @simplyTom: As I said, Ministro downloads ARM ports of Qt C/C++ libraries, AFAICT. You cannot silently install APK files, outside of writing custom firmware.